# Asp.net core using serilog, filters and rolling files

Tags: appsettings, asp.net-core-2.0, serilog

i need to configure appsettings to use serilog log and to separate same classes (identityserver4, query sql, application ) and redirect the output in dfferent file to analyze tha program flow.

I've installed serilog, serilog.settings.configuration, serilog.sinks.rollingfile, serilog.filters.extensions and serilog.sinks.console but i've not found some documentation to do that.

This is my Serilog section in appsetting:

```
  "Serilog": {
    "MinimumLevel": {
      "Default": "Debug",
        "Override": {
          "Microsoft": "Warning",
          "System": "Warning"
        }
      },
    "WriteTo": [
      { "Name": "LiterateConsole" },
      {
        "Name": "RollingFile",
        "Args": { "pathFormat": "Logs/log-{Date}.txt" }
      },
      {
        "Name": "RollingFile",
        "pathFormat": "Logs/DBCommands-{Date}.log",
        "Filter": [
          {
            "Name": "ByIncludingOnly",
            "Args": {
              "expression": "SourceContext = 'IdentityServer4'"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "Enrich": [ "FromLogContext", "WithMachineName", "WithThreadId" ],
      "Properties": {
        "Application": "dsm.security"
      }
    }
```

Where i'm wrong ?

**UPDATE**
I would like to have the same result that i can obtain with the following code

```
        Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .MinimumLevel.Debug()
            .ReadFrom.Configuration(Configuration)
            .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft", LogEventLevel.Information)
            .MinimumLevel.Override("System", LogEventLevel.Warning)
            .MinimumLevel.Override("Default", LogEventLevel.Warning)
            .Enrich.FromLogContext()
            .WriteTo.Console(theme: AnsiConsoleTheme.Code)
            .WriteTo.Logger(l => l.Filter.ByIncludingOnly(e => e.Level == LogEventLevel.Error).WriteTo.RollingFile(@"Logs/Error-{Date}.log"))
            .WriteTo.Logger(l => l.Filter.ByIncludingOnly(e => e.Level == LogEventLevel.Fatal).WriteTo.RollingFile(@"Logs/Fatal-{Date}.log"))
            .WriteTo.Logger(l => l.Filter.ByIncludingOnly(Matching.FromSource("dsm.security")).WriteTo.RollingFile(@"Logs/dsm.security-{Date}.log"))
            .WriteTo.Logger(l => l.Filter.ByIncludingOnly(Matching.FromSource("IdentityServer4")).WriteTo.RollingFile(@"Logs/IdentityServer-{Date}.log"))
            .WriteTo.Logger(l => l.Filter.ByIncludingOnly(Matching.FromSource("Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore")).WriteTo.RollingFile(@"Logs/EF-{Date}.log"))
            //                .WriteTo.RollingFile(@"Logs/Verbose-{Date}.log")
            .CreateLogger();
```

Comment: What behaviour are you seeing? Also, have you tried adding `"Using": ["Serilog.Filters.Expressions"]`? HTH!